# Elastic NEST Automap()

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to create a new index in Elastic Cloud, and am trying to use the AutoMap functionality to generate the mapping for my products, I am wondering if someone who has done this can tell me how long this generally takes, my application has been running for over 90 mins consuming all my RAM and the index has not yet appeared on Elastic.

can anyone offer any advice?

```
var node = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("https://elasticcloud:9243"));
var config = new ConnectionSettings(
                    node,
                    new HttpConnection());
var client = new ElasticClient(config);     
client.CreateIndex("sbproducts", i => i
                .Settings(s => s
                .NumberOfShards(2)
                .NumberOfReplicas(0)
                )
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<Data.Product>(m => m.AutoMap())
                )
                );
```

Comment: It should be more or less immediate. Did you check the return value of the `client.CreateIndex(...)` method call?

Comment: If I remove the mappings it happens immediately but with the .Mappings part it just crawls and consumes all the RAM.

Comment: If I take the index out of the equation and just try and map the products like so 

var descriptor = (ITypeMapping)new TypeMappingDescriptor<Data.Product>().AutoMap();

 I get the same issue Memory usage flies to 10GB+ within seconds and it just sits there.

Comment: Can you show what the class `Data.Product` looks like?

Comment: @RussCam it does have references to just about every other class which is my  guess as to what the problem Is I guess I will have to manually define all the mappings.

Comment: Are any of those references circular?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
.Map<Data.Product>(m => m.AutoMap())
```

<strike>By default does not protect against circular references there is an overload that takes `maxRecursion` as an integer.</strike>

**UPDATE**

The default recursion is `0` which means it won't recurse into a type it has already seen. Any additional information you can give us on your type would be appreciated @rs82uk

Comment: Opened https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/2917 to bake a new default max recursion of `20` vs `0` (unbounded).

Comment: The default recursion is 0 which means it won't recurse into a type it has already seen. Any additional information you can give us on your type would be appreciated @rs82uk

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this originally and got moved on to a different project.It does have references back to itself it is a database first MVC site i have inherited